# Best way to load and store data at request level

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

**Scenario:** I have a Rest API, where we are fetching some data and on basis of some db data, we are applying rules.
**Current Implementation:** So, I have fetched all the data required for rules in one shot and stored it in HashMap.
DataStructure looks like this - **ConcurrentMap<String,HashMap<String,Rules>>.**

The outer map contains uses the request_id as key and inner contains rule'key.
Also, outer map is concurrenthashmap and inner one is hashmap.

The **problem** comes as this application is multithreaded and when threads try to read the rule, they have to go through the lock in the concurrenthashmap.SO, from a performance perspective, I think this does not sound good.

I wanted to check if there is a better way to implement this scenario.

Comment: Find a caching library that allows you to read without locking if it's sure the data is already there. One example could be Caffeine, which is a fork of the Guava Cache.

Comment: From a performance perspective, you should _measure_ performance, not guess it like some kind of mystical oracle.

Comment: @Jorn - Data is there but has to be loaded at the request level, as the request will have a deciding parameter, the outer map will have read/write operation but the inner is a write once operation.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a good fit for that Cache then

Answer (score 3):

The point of `ConcurrentMap` class is that it does NOT use locks. So, you should be OK.

Comment: [Exactly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): "However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access".

Comment: Well, it locks but only locks the given bucket I believe?